# Create custom JSON string from form

Tags: jquery, json, forms, serialization

I have a form I'd like to submit as JSON via jQuery AJAX, so that I can read it into a temporary table on the server-side using one my programming language's native methods (OpenEdge using READ-JSON). An example of the JSON my form needs to produce is:

```
{"ttOrder": [
  {
    "cProduct": "prod01",
    "iQty": 123
  },
  {
    "cProduct": "prod02",
    "iQty": 456
  }
]}
```

My form is made up of a table containing rows of product information, product code, description etc. and a quantity input field, e.g.

```
<input id="prod01" name="prod01" value="0">
```

From searching around Stack Overflow I found a couple of suggestions that looked like they might help, as I think I need to serialise the form:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.serializeJSON=function() {
        var json = {};
        jQuery.map($(this).serializeArray(), function(n, i){
            json[n['name']] = n['value'];
        });
        return json;
    };
})( jQuery );

var obj = {"ttOrder": [$('#prodform').serializeJSON() ]};
```

And then in the $.ajax call use

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
...
```

However, this gives the following:

```
{"ttOrder": [
  {
    "prod01": "123",
    "prod02": "456"
  }
]}
```

I think that all the code above is doing is creating a JSON string comprising of the input name and value as a key & value pair, but I don't have the know-how to change the code to get me what I require.

I think that what I'm trying to achieve is to have an array of objects where the name of the array is always ttOrder (maps to my temp-table name), the first entry of an object is the product code (always cProduct - maps to my temp-table field name) with a value of the input's name, and the second entry of an object is the quantity (always iQty - maps to my temp-table field value).

Please excuse any incorrect terminology I use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example is close.  This should work here:

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.serializeJSON=function() {
    return jQuery.map($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, n){
        var json = {};
        json['cProduct'] = n['name'];
        json['iQty'] = parseInt(n['value']);

        return json;

    }).get();
};
})( jQuery );

var obj = {"ttOrder": $('#prodform').serializeJSON()};
```

Comment: Brilliant, and thanks for such a quick solution. It almost works, but the quantity is being turned into a string i.e.
    `{"cProduct": "01", "iQty": "1"}` rather than `{"cProduct": "01", "iQty": 1}`. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Adding a parseInt around n['value'] should do the trick: json['iQty'] = parseInt(n['value']);